# Using wp_tag_cloud('format=array') to print tag names without links?

Tags: theme-development, tags

I'm trying to pull just the tag names as an array collection in order to write them out as a simple listing, without links, but the array that's returned does not send the name as an indexible item.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> string(129) "<a href='#' class='tag-link-31' title='1 topic' style='font-size: 8pt;'>tag 1</a>"
  [1]=> string(127) "<a href='#' class='tag-link-30' title='1 topic' style='font-size: 8pt;'>tag 2</a>"
}
```

Is there another method I can use to get the entire site's tag collection with just the tag names? This is my current code, but because of the array indexes, I get the links as well.

```
$tagNames = wp_tag_cloud('format=array');
echo implode($tagNames,", ");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try :

```
function my_tag_list_123($sep){
    $tags = get_tags();

    foreach ($tags as $tag){
        $ret[]= $tag->name;
    }
    return implode($sep, $ret);
}
```

and call it when you need like this

```
echo my_tag_list_123(',');
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks very much. That did it. Can get_tags() be used to find matches on the current post only, if in the loop?

Comment: Use `get_the_tags()` in place of `get_tags`.. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php 
        $args = array(
        'smallest'                  => 12, 
        'largest'                   => 12,
        'unit'                      => 'pt', 
        'number'                    => 0,  
        'format'                    => 'array',
        'separator'                 => "",
        'orderby'                   => 'name', 
        'order'                     => 'ASC',
        'exclude'                   => null, 
        'include'                   => null, 
        'topic_count_text_callback' => default_topic_count_text,
        'link'                      => 'view', 
        'taxonomy'                  => 'post_tag', 
        'echo'                      => true,
        'child_of'                  => null, // see Note!
        );      

        $myCloud = wp_tag_cloud( $args );

        foreach ($myCloud as $tag) {
            $tag = strip_tags($tag);
            echo '<li>' . $tag . '</li>';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Please explain your code. Dumping of code like this without any explanation does not make a good answer and should be avoided. Please file an [edit] and add a proper explanation how your code works